# Mounting Full Motion Mount on a Single Stud

Tags: installation, mounting, studs, drywall-anchor, television

I've seen this question regarding a sheet metal stud, but my plan and situation are a bit different.

I am curious if ananyone thinks this sounds secure: 
I have a full motion flat screen wall mount for "up to 70 in." televisions. My tv is 50 inches and weighs approximately 50 lbs. The mount weighs maybe 15 lbs and is only 16 inches long (studs over my fireplace are 22 inches apart). There is however, one stud directly in the center.

Is it safe to attach the mount to the single stud with two 2.5 inch lag bolts at the top and bottom center, and 100 lb rated drywall anchors on all four corners?

Comment: Not sure, but this feels like possible trouble over the long run. If the mount rocks side to side at all as you adjust it, it may start to punch through the drywall. Another answer might be to support a nice-looking wooden panel with several studs and attach the wall-mount to that.

Comment: I agree with @keshlam - attach a board to the wall that spans several studs, and attach the mount to the board.

Comment: I also agree. While it may not be an issue at first drywall is not very strong for a repetitive motion like the one that will occur with the movement of the TV. I do think you can get lag bolts that are strong enough. Eventually though you'll crack your drywall and maybe go through it and have endless repair issues. Every time you twist the TV on the wall it will put an angular pressure on the drywall opposite of the turn.

Answer (score 1):

Toggles and other heavy weight drywall anchors can be suitable for TV mounts when the mount is flush. Or toggles in to metal studs. Since the load is mostly shear and not pull-out, this is fairly safe. (Provided the drywall is thick enough, the anchors are installed correctly, the wall is properly supported, and lots of other considerations too numerous to go in to here.)

However, adjustable, articulating or arm mounts should *never* be used on just drywall or metal studs. No matter what anchor you use, drywall and metal studs can not handle the pull out force applied when a TV is extended or tilted away from the wall.

So either get a flush mount, or open the drywall and install appropriate wooden studs.

Comment: This is what OP's heading for: http://handmadeartists.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/plasma_lcd_tv_hang_fail.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If it is a single metal stud, I would suggest you look into the [snaptoggles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dl2p0s3iZDI) (aka toggle straps, toggler bolts) that you can attach to metal studs and/or drywall. and if it is a wood stud in the middle, consider using the same snaptoggles for the other 4 corners that are only in drywall since they claim to hold over 200 lbs. in 1/2 inch drywall.

I am also planning to mount into drywall that has metal studs and as the other commenter suggested, I plan to go with the [wood panel support solution](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/48118/can-metal-studs-support-a-64-plasma-tv-on-a-swiveling-mount)

thanks.

Comment: This answer seems to be part answer, and part comment.  Could you please remove the "comment" portion of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is exactly what I would do and I have mounted hundreds of TVs.  I have mounted lots of larger / heavier TVs on drywall only with high quality anchors.  Hit that one stud and it will carry the lion's share of the weight, the anchors will just keep it nice and flat.  Just make sure you really hit the stud!

My suggestions:

Don't just trust a stud finder.  Drill a series of tiny holes horizontally so you know right where the center of the stud is.  You can also just poke a finishing nail or etc through the drywall.  These holes will be behind the mount so they won't be visible.  (If you ever remove the mount you'll have to paint anyway.)

Use 1/4" lag screws and washers, washers are important.   Drill a 3/16" pilot hole for the lag screws.  Get it tight but not so tight it deforms the sheet metal.  This only takes a few minutes and will make it as strong as possible.  These two lags could carry way more than the weight of the TV.

Now in the corners, I have a specific product suggestion:

http://www.toggler.com/products/snaptoggle/overview.php

I'd use the Snaptoggle BB, the 1/4" size.  You could probably hold the mount and TV with just these without hitting the stud, but it's safer to hit the stud.

Comment: I'm in exactly the same position as the OP, but unsure I will be able to use a stud to mount the tv. This not for execution reasons, but rather for room layout reasons. I will be using snaptoggles for the mount. Your closing comment that "you could probably hold the mount and tv [..] without hitting the stud" is interesting to me. My tv weighs in at 33lbs. Thoughts?